# What is the best way to inject mocked Spring @Autowired dependencies from a unit test?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, mocking, autowired

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

class MyService {
  @Autowired private DependencyOne dependencyOne;
  @Autowired private DependencyTwo dependencyTwo;

  public void doSomething(){
    //Does something with dependencies
  }
}
```

When testing this class, I basically have four ways to inject mock dependencies:

1. Use Spring's ReflectionTestUtils in the test to inject the dependencies
2. Add a constructor to MyService
3. Add setter methods to MyService
4. Relax the dependency visibility to package-protected and set the fields directly

Which is the best and why?

--- UPDATE ---

I guess I should have been a bit clearer - I am only talking about "unit" style tests, not Spring "integration" style tests where dependencies can be wired in using a Spring context.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `ReflectionTestUtils` or put a setter. Either is fine. Adding constructors can have side effects (disallow subclassing by CGLIB for example), and relaxing the visibility just for the sake of testing is not a good approach.

Comment: That's usually what I end up doing as well (ReflectionTestUtils). In my opinion, this in one of the few major weaknesses in Spring, the lack of support for easily replacing/mocking beans directly into the context.

Comment: "this in one of the few major weaknesses in Spring, the lack of support for easily replacing/mocking beans directly into the context" - but there is no Spring context in his unit test. He is simply `new`ing the MyService class.

Comment: @matt b - it doesn't matter - the question is about the possibilities of setting dependencies.

Comment: Setters are ugly because they are only used by the tests, and RefelectionTestUtils is ugly because it doesn't keep up with field name refactorings. Which is less ugly?

Comment: setters :) because they are the normal way of setting dependencies. Spring uses field reflection to do that, but it could've been a using setter reflection (bean properties)

Answer (score 3):

Spring's ContextConfiguration can do this for you.

For example, in the test context below the "Local" classes are mocks.  `NotificationService` is the class I want to test.

I am using component scanning to bring the mocks into the context but you can just as easily use `<bean>` declarations.   Note the use of use-default-filters="false".

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.config" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="assignable" 
        expression="com.foo.LocalNotificationConfig"/>
</context:component-scan>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.services.notification"
        use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="assignable"
        expression="com.foo.services.notification.DelegatingTemplateService"/>
    <context:include-filter type="assignable"
        expression="com.foo.services.notification.NotificationService"/>
</context:component-scan>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.domain"/>
```

DelegatingTemplateService is a Groovy class with a @Delegate.

```
class DelegatingTemplateService {
  @Delegate
  TemplateService delegate
}
```

In the test class I use the test context and inject the service to test.   In the setup I set the delegate of the DelegatingTemplateService:

```
@RunWith(classOf[SpringJUnit4ClassRunner])
@ContextConfiguration(Array("/spring-test-context.xml"))
class TestNotificationService extends JUnitSuite {
  @Autowired var notificationService: NotificationService = _
  @Autowired var templateService: DelegatingTemplateService = _

  @Before
  def setUp {
    templateService.delegate = /* Your dynamic mock here */
  }
```

In the service the @Autowired fields are private:

```
@Component("notificationService")
class NotificationServiceImpl extends NotificationService {
  @Autowired private var domainManager: DomainManager = _
  @Autowired private var templateService: TemplateService = _
  @Autowired private var notificationConfig: NotificationConfig = _
```

Comment: yes, you can swap implementations for test and production. But I had in mind mocks generated at runtime with something like Mockito, hence my answer.

Comment: gotcha - how about using a Groovy @Delegate?  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

2) Use @Autowired constructor injection (if that's what option 2 was; otherwise, make an option 5)

Proper constructors that create an object in a valid state is a more correctly object-oriented approach, and losing cglib proxies is relatively unimportant since we all code to interfaces anyway, right??